# Segmenttation fault (core dumped) in snmpd after upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: segmentation-fault

The 15 Ubuntu 18.04 systems within our company, I am upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.
The upgrade runs smoothly and takes +/- 40 minutes.
However, I do have the problem that the snmpd crashed after a few days.

```
error on subcontainer 'ifTable container' remove (-1)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

However, even though "ulimit -c" has the value "unlimited" and there are write permissions in the directory, I don't see a core file.

This crash also occurs when I start the snmpd manually with the arguments below:

```
snmpd -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -f -p /run/snmpd.pid
```

This problem doesn't occur on systems that are directly installed with Ubuntu 20.
The file /etc/snmp/snmpd.conf is on all systems the same.

The system is upgraded from 18.04.6 to 20.04.6
During this upgrade the snmpd is upgraded
from 5.7.3+dfsg-1.8ubuntu3.8 (bionic)
to   5.8+dfsg-2ubuntu2.6 (focal)

What is that "subcontainer 'ifTable container'" ?

With the debugger 'gdb' is got a core stack trace.
gdb /usr/sbin/snmpd
(gdb) run -u Debian-snmp -g Debian-snmp -f -p /run/snmpd.pid
error on subcontainer 'ifTable container' remove (-1)
error on subcontainer 'ifTable container' remove (-1)

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__GI___libc_free (mem=0x150) at malloc.c:3102
3102    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) bt
#0  __GI___libc_free (mem=0x150) at malloc.c:3102
#1  0x00007ffff7d8003b in netsnmp_access_interface_entry_free ()
from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmpmibs.so.35
#2  0x00007ffff7d557e8 in ifTable_rowreq_ctx_cleanup ()
from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmpmibs.so.35
#3  0x00007ffff7d83ef2 in ifTable_release_rowreq_ctx ()
from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmpmibs.so.35
#4  0x00007ffff7bd1878 in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmp.so.35
#5  0x00007ffff7d85fc8 in ifTable_container_load ()
from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmpmibs.so.35
#6  0x00007ffff7f604ad in ?? () from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmpagent.so.35
#7  0x00007ffff7bab4d7 in run_alarms ()
from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnetsnmp.so.35
#8  0x0000555555559864 in ?? ()
#9  0x000055555555910d in main ()

What is the next step to solve this problem?

Comment: Or do you mean Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04?

Comment: Looks like it could be this (old) but which seems to crop up again and again. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/net-snmp/+bug/720638

Comment: The crash occurs after an upgrade from 18.04.6 to 20.4.5
In /var/log/syslog I found the next information:
snmpd[1196129]: segfault at 148 ip 00007f9c886756f0 sp 00007ffcd9bb41c0 error 4 in libc-2.31.so[7f9c885fd000+178000]